# simplifying a long list of click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I'm using an image slider on my site: http://arirang.hr/cocohouse/accommodation/CHfood_en.html . It works well for me.

When visitor click a thumbnail below the slider it jumps to the particular image. It's done by having a click function for the each thumbnail. Started with few thumbnails only. Having quite a lot now. Ended up with a long list of click functions there.

Guess that a proper way should be by some kind of loop there. When visitor clicks any thumbnail to start the loop that finds which one is clicked and call the cycle with the clicked number.

Comment: show your code, probably going to be better to use jquery to add function to click event

Comment: There are lots of tutorials out there which you can study and come up here if you face any issues in them..

Answer (score 0):

Change all your images to use a class instead of ids like:

```
<input type="image" class="goTo" src="../images/cocohouse/accommodation/thumbnails/tn_CHfood_29.png" width="80" height="60">
```

Then, do this:

```
$('.goTo').click(function( event ) { 
    event.preventDefault(); // you dont need this line for your code, see comment below for explanation  
    var cur = $('.goTo').index( $(this) );
    $('#acc_sl').cycle(cur); 
});
```

Comment: had an error "Undefined $this...

Removed $ from index($this).  

Now
.....

 var cur = $('.goTo').index(this); 

.........
Works OK    !!
Thanks

Comment: Yep, my bad, should have been either `$(this)` or `this`, updated above. As an FYI, The `return false` is usually an attempt to prevent some default action. For example, if you were to bind a click handler to a link, the browser might navigate to that link before the code in the handler has a chance to run. However, the right way to do that would be to call `event.preventDefault();` at the top of the handler. Note that I added the 'event' parameter in the handler: `...function( event ) { `, this parameter is available by default in handlers but you have to list it if you want to use it.

Comment: Just to be clear, you dont need `event.preventDefault();` for your use, I only mention it to clarify what your original `return false` was seemingly meant for (you probably got your original code from somewhere that needed it and you didnt know any different)

Answer (score -1):

first off u should present some sort of effort of what you have done so far. This is not a site where you can order solutions.

To fix your problem you should have one function that takes image name or some sort of identifier as an argument. That way you only use one function for every picture.

Comment: BTW i am not a downvoter but are you anwering the question or trying to comment on the question?

Comment: I like to think its an answer. Not providing the whole solution. The questing shows that the user doesn't practise reuse of code which makes me assume that there are fundamental steps missing which is ok while learning. Can't know everything from start right? My answer is that the user needs to have a different approach than the one he has now. To write the function him self or using a lib doesn't matter, its how u tackle the problem thats important.

Comment: That's it Skjaar.  Highly appreciated :)
Not so easy to master the programming. That might be an excuse for a bit of arrogance with some inputs here.

Comment: Downvote was because this comment, while somewhat true, is better suited as a comment, not an answer. Additionally, you stated "first off u should present some sort of effort of what you have done so far." While the OP did not present their code here (and yes, they should have), they did give a link to a live site that uses their code and indeed shows the "effort of what they've done so far." The rest of the answer, while true, is entirely too vague to be of any help to the OP, you could have at least mentioned using a class instead of ids.

Comment: I see now.. my comment came out of the context here..appreciate all your inputs guys...  fills great knowing there are guys there keen to put you onto the right track with things..This is basically my first..  Should have looked into the rules before asking for help  :( . Next time I'll do it better.  A great help anyhow..  .....Thanks a lot..